# Remove/Add content blocks from sidebar "Not Home-page" Magento

Tags: magento, templates, layout, positioning, sidebar

Im new to magento and cant quite find the answer im looking for. I just bought a template and its going fine expect that I just modify the layout of my sidebar category/product view page. (I have homepage sorted via admin panel).

Basically how do I go about adding and removing content blocks from my sidebar?

PS: Does magento have some sort of cheat sheet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

within local.xml

```
<layout_handle>
   <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />  

   <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />  <!--product compare-->


   <remove name="left.reports.product.viewed" /> <!--recently viewed prod-->

</layout_handle>"
```

this way you can remove whatever blocks you want to.